# Traverse implied edge through property match?

Tags: gremlin

I'm trying to create edges between vertices based on matching the value of a property in each vertex, making what is currently an implied relationship into an explicit relationship. I've been unsuccessful in writing a gremlin traversal that will match up related vertices.

Specifically, given the following graph:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV('person').property('name','alice')
g.addV('person').property('name','bob').property('spouse','carol')
g.addV('person').property('name','carol')
g.addV('person').property('name','dave').property('spouse', 'alice')
```

I was hoping I could create a `spouse_of` relation using the following

```
> g.V().has('spouse').as('x')
   .V().has('name', select('x').by('spouse'))
       .addE('spouse_of').from('x')
```

but instead of creating one edge from `bob` to `carol` and another edge from `dave` to `alice`, `bob` and `dave` each end up with `spouse_of` edges to *all* of the vertices (including themselves):

```
> g.V().out('spouse_of').path().by('name')
  ==>[bob,alice]
  ==>[bob,bob]
  ==>[bob,carol]
  ==>[bob,dave]
  ==>[dave,carol]
  ==>[dave,dave]
  ==>[dave,alice]
  ==>[dave,bob]
```

It almost seems as if the `has` filter isn't being applied, or, to use RDBMS terms, as if I'm ending up with an "outer join" instead of the "inner join" I'd intended.

Any suggestions? Am I overlooking something trivial or profound (local vs global scope, perhaps)? Is there *any* way of accomplishing this in a single traversal query, or do I have to iterate through  `g.has('spouse')` and create edges individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this happen in a single traversal, but `has()` is not meant to work quite that way. The pattern for this is type of traversal is described in the [Traversal Induced Values](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#traversal-induced-values) section of the Gremlin Recipes tutorial, but you can see it in action here:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').has('spouse').as('s').
......1>   V().hasLabel('person').as('x').
......2>   where('x', eq('s')).
......3>     by('name').
......4>     by('spouse').
......5>   addE('spouse_of').from('s').to('x')
==>e[10][2-spouse_of->5]
==>e[11][7-spouse_of->0]
gremlin> g.E().project('x','y').by(outV().values('name')).by(inV().values('name'))
==>[x:bob,y:carol]
==>[x:dave,y:alice]
```

While this can be done in a single traversal note that depending on the size of your data this could be an expensive traversal as I'm not sure that either call to `V()` will be optimized by any graph. While it's neat to use this form, you may find that it's faster to take approaches that ensure that a use of an index is in place which might mean issuing multiple queries to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. This was actually an oversimplified example of a larger reasoning process that will only need to be done once (to add the relation to existing data), subsequent updates will create the `spouse` edges explicitly as part of vertex creation.